# PyInstaller: ValueError: Module file ... is missing

Tags: python, pyinstaller

To protect my code, I convert test.py to test.pyd.

test.py and test.pyd are now in the same folder.

Then I use ***pyinstaller -F test.py*** to get exe. As far as I know, pyd has higer priority than py, so pyinstaller will try to get code from test.pyd, right?

Anyway, I got this error after using the above command: **ValueError: Module file .../test.py is missing**.

If there is only test.py in the folder, the command works just fine. So why it shows this error when test.pyd is also in the folder...and how to solve this...
[image]

PyInstaller==3.4  Python==3.6.8

Comment: Not sure Pyinstaller can handle pyd files but try both `hidden-import` and `add-data`: `pyinstaller --hidden-import=yourmodule --add-data "yourmodule.pyd;." script.py"`.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me when I tried `pyinstaller entrypoint.spec` based on `entrypoint.py`, when I discovered I had accidentally created the file `entrypoint.pyd` in the same folder. Removing the `pyd` file resolved the issue.

Comment: Hello, and welcome. The OP would like to use the .pyd file, so this does not seem to resolve the issue.

Comment: So it does, my apologies.